# Сколько живет отрицательное значение этой функции isGuest?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

**Сколько живет отрицательное значение этой функции isGuest?** Оно живет пока не исчезнет куки или и сессии тоже? 
Дело в том, что она не работает в базовом примере. Если ты хоть один раз был залогинен, и в login("test", 60 ); установил время жизни кукам, то ты все равно будешь залогиным, даже если закроешь браузер и откроешь его через 10-ть лет.

Comment: Насчет десяти лет проверяли?

Comment: @newman Ну, 10 не проверял, а три года , да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле /config/params.php устанавливаем значение

```
'sessionTimeoutSeconds' => '1800',
```

В контроллере, где у вас метод actionLogin() добавьте:

```
Yii::$app->session->set('userSessionTimeout', time() + Yii::$app->params['sessionTimeoutSeconds']);
```

Создайте метод beforeAction в контроллере

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{

    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check only when the user is logged in
    if ( !Yii::$app->user->isGuest)  {
        if (Yii::$app->session['userSessionTimeout'] < time()) {
            Yii::$app->user->logout();
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->set('userSessionTimeout', time() + Yii::$app->params['sessionTimeoutSeconds']);
            return true; 
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Находим файл views/layouts/main.php. В самом верху, где подключены мета теги и title добавляем:

```
<? if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { ?>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo Yii::$app->params['sessionTimeoutSeconds'];?>;"/>
<? } ?>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859333/yii-users-being-logged-out-after-15-30-minutes-despite-session-timeouts-being-se/31008088#31008088)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/74160)

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade Это не решение проблемы Но всё равно спасибо

Comment: @ermak0ff Спасибо. Я новичок. Уже все понял) Поправил.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Вы сделали все, как я описал? Может у вас в самом php.ini недочеты? Проверьте настройки php.ini, а так код рабочий. Сам решал данную проблему таким образом.

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade а если юзер не захочет чтобы запоминали его данные? Вы же для всех юзеров устанавливаете по умолчанию сохранения кук в браузере.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов тогда поставьте checbox и проверяйте по нему. По умолчанию поставьте сколько хотите, а если выбран checkbox, то для него также отдельно выставите значение.

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade тогда в гугле хром опять этаже проблема будет. Ну или в том браузеере который сохраняет сессионные куки.

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade Если вам нужно чтобы сессия форсированно очищалась через 60 секунд, то можно сделать так. В файле index.php между require_once и Yii::createWebApplication добавьте следующий код:  ---- это цитата, найдите это где-то тут.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38353/discussion-between-urmuz-tagizade-and--).

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade Я зашел, вас уже так не было. Вы если что пишите тут.

Comment: Вы решили проблему?

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade Да. Я вам цитату привел, она где-то тут.